# Why is only the html code shown and not also the three js code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js

Today I wanted to run a sample three js game but only the html code showed up. I also installed three js with npm. I tried to run it with the vsc lice server but it doesn't work.

Here the source code: https://codepen.io/HunorMarton/pen/MWjBRWp. What can I try next?

```js
import * as THREE from 'three';


window.onload = function() {
    window.focus(); 
let camera, scene, renderer; 
let world; 
let lastTime; 
let stack; 
let overhangs; 
const boxHeight = 1; 
const originalBoxSize = 3; 
let autopilot;
let gameEnded;
let robotPrecision; 

const scoreElement = document.getElementById("score");
const instructionsElement = document.getElementById("instructions");
const resultsElement = document.getElementById("results");

init();


function setRobotPrecision() {
  robotPrecision = Math.random() * 1 - 0.5;
}

function init() {
  autopilot = true;
  gameEnded = false;
  lastTime = 0;
  stack = [];
  overhangs = [];
  setRobotPrecision();

  
  world = new CANNON.World();
  world.gravity.set(0, -10, 0); 
  world.broadphase = new CANNON.NaiveBroadphase();
  world.solver.iterations = 40;

  
  const aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  const width = 10;
  const height = width / aspect;

  camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(
    width / -2, 
    width / 2, 
    height / 2, 
    height / -2, 
    0, 
    100 
  );

  

  camera.position.set(4, 4, 4);
  camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  
  addLayer(0, 0, originalBoxSize, originalBoxSize);

  
  addLayer(-10, 0, originalBoxSize, originalBoxSize, "x");

  
  const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.6);
  scene.add(ambientLight);

  const dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.6);
  dirLight.position.set(10, 20, 0);
  scene.add(dirLight);

  
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  renderer.setAnimationLoop(animation);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
}

function startGame() {
  autopilot = false;
  gameEnded = false;
  lastTime = 0;
  stack = [];
  overhangs = [];

  if (instructionsElement) instructionsElement.style.display = "none";
  if (resultsElement) resultsElement.style.display = "none";
  if (scoreElement) scoreElement.innerText = 0;

  if (world) {
    
    while (world.bodies.length > 0) {
      world.remove(world.bodies[0]);
    }
  }

  if (scene) {
   
    while (scene.children.find((c) => c.type == "Mesh")) {
      const mesh = scene.children.find((c) => c.type == "Mesh");
      scene.remove(mesh);
    }

   
    addLayer(0, 0, originalBoxSize, originalBoxSize);

    
    addLayer(-10, 0, originalBoxSize, originalBoxSize, "x");
  }

  if (camera) {
   
    camera.position.set(4, 4, 4);
    camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

function addLayer(x, z, width, depth, direction) {
  const y = boxHeight * stack.length; 
  const layer = generateBox(x, y, z, width, depth, false);
  layer.direction = direction;
  stack.push(layer);
}

function addOverhang(x, z, width, depth) {
  const y = boxHeight * (stack.length - 1); 
  const overhang = generateBox(x, y, z, width, depth, true);
  overhangs.push(overhang);
}

function generateBox(x, y, z, width, depth, falls) {
  
  const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(width, boxHeight, depth);
  const color = new THREE.Color(`hsl(${30 + stack.length * 4}, 100%, 50%)`);
  const material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color });
  const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  mesh.position.set(x, y, z);
  scene.add(mesh);

  
  const shape = new CANNON.Box(
    new CANNON.Vec3(width / 2, boxHeight / 2, depth / 2)
  );
  let mass = falls ? 5 : 0; 
  mass *= width / originalBoxSize; 
  mass *= depth / originalBoxSize; 
  const body = new CANNON.Body({ mass, shape });
  body.position.set(x, y, z);
  world.addBody(body);

  return {
    threejs: mesh,
    cannonjs: body,
    width,
    depth
  };
}

function cutBox(topLayer, overlap, size, delta) {
  const direction = topLayer.direction;
  const newWidth = direction == "x" ? overlap : topLayer.width;
  const newDepth = direction == "z" ? overlap : topLayer.depth;

  
  topLayer.width = newWidth;
  topLayer.depth = newDepth;

  
  topLayer.threejs.scale[direction] = overlap / size;
  topLayer.threejs.position[direction] -= delta / 2;

  
  topLayer.cannonjs.position[direction] -= delta / 2;

  
  const shape = new CANNON.Box(
    new CANNON.Vec3(newWidth / 2, boxHeight / 2, newDepth / 2)
  );
  topLayer.cannonjs.shapes = [];
  topLayer.cannonjs.addShape(shape);
}

window.addEventListener("mousedown", eventHandler);
window.addEventListener("touchstart", eventHandler);
window.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
  if (event.key == " ") {
    event.preventDefault();
    eventHandler();
    return;
  }
  if (event.key == "R" || event.key == "r") {
    event.preventDefault();
    startGame();
    return;
  }
});

function eventHandler() {
  if (autopilot) startGame();
  else splitBlockAndAddNextOneIfOverlaps();
}

function splitBlockAndAddNextOneIfOverlaps() {
  if (gameEnded) return;

  const topLayer = stack[stack.length - 1];
  const previousLayer = stack[stack.length - 2];

  const direction = topLayer.direction;

  const size = direction == "x" ? topLayer.width : topLayer.depth;
  const delta =
    topLayer.threejs.position[direction] -
    previousLayer.threejs.position[direction];
  const overhangSize = Math.abs(delta);
  const overlap = size - overhangSize;

  if (overlap > 0) {
    cutBox(topLayer, overlap, size, delta);

    
    const overhangShift = (overlap / 2 + overhangSize / 2) * Math.sign(delta);
    const overhangX =
      direction == "x"
        ? topLayer.threejs.position.x + overhangShift
        : topLayer.threejs.position.x;
    const overhangZ =
      direction == "z"
        ? topLayer.threejs.position.z + overhangShift
        : topLayer.threejs.position.z;
    const overhangWidth = direction == "x" ? overhangSize : topLayer.width;
    const overhangDepth = direction == "z" ? overhangSize : topLayer.depth;

    addOverhang(overhangX, overhangZ, overhangWidth, overhangDepth);

    
    const nextX = direction == "x" ? topLayer.threejs.position.x : -10;
    const nextZ = direction == "z" ? topLayer.threejs.position.z : -10;
    const newWidth = topLayer.width; 
    const newDepth = topLayer.depth; 
    const nextDirection = direction == "x" ? "z" : "x";

    if (scoreElement) scoreElement.innerText = stack.length - 1;
    addLayer(nextX, nextZ, newWidth, newDepth, nextDirection);
  } else {
    missedTheSpot();
  }
}

function missedTheSpot() {
  const topLayer = stack[stack.length - 1];

  
  addOverhang(
    topLayer.threejs.position.x,
    topLayer.threejs.position.z,
    topLayer.width,
    topLayer.depth
  );
  world.remove(topLayer.cannonjs);
  scene.remove(topLayer.threejs);

  gameEnded = true;
  if (resultsElement && !autopilot) resultsElement.style.display = "flex";
}

function animation(time) {
  if (lastTime) {
    const timePassed = time - lastTime;
    const speed = 0.008;

    const topLayer = stack[stack.length - 1];
    const previousLayer = stack[stack.length - 2];

    
    const boxShouldMove =
      !gameEnded &&
      (!autopilot ||
        (autopilot &&
          topLayer.threejs.position[topLayer.direction] <
            previousLayer.threejs.position[topLayer.direction] +
              robotPrecision));

    if (boxShouldMove) {
      
      topLayer.threejs.position[topLayer.direction] += speed * timePassed;
      topLayer.cannonjs.position[topLayer.direction] += speed * timePassed;

      
      if (topLayer.threejs.position[topLayer.direction] > 10) {
        missedTheSpot();
      }
    } else {
      
      if (autopilot) {
        splitBlockAndAddNextOneIfOverlaps();
        setRobotPrecision();
      }
    }

    
    if (camera.position.y < boxHeight * (stack.length - 2) + 4) {
      camera.position.y += speed * timePassed;
    }

    updatePhysics(timePassed);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }
  lastTime = time;
}

function updatePhysics(timePassed) {
  world.step(timePassed / 1000); 

  
  overhangs.forEach((element) => {
    element.threejs.position.copy(element.cannonjs.position);
    element.threejs.quaternion.copy(element.cannonjs.quaternion);
  });
}

window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
 
  console.log("resize", window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  const aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  const width = 10;
  const height = width / aspect;

  camera.top = height / 2;
  camera.bottom = height / -2;

  
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});

  };
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@900&display=swap");

body {
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#instructions {
  display: none;
}

#results,
body:hover #instructions {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.75);
}

a:visited {
  color: inherit;
}

#results {
  display: none;
  cursor: default;
}

#results .content,
#instructions .content {
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 50px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

#results {
}

#score {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  top: 30px;
  right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="instructions">
        <div class="content">
          <p>Stack the blocks on top of each other</p>
          <p>Click, tap or press Space when a block is above the stack. Can you reach the blue color blocks?</p>
          <p>Click, tap or press Space to start game</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="results">
        <div class="content">
          <p>You missed the block</p>
          <p>To reset the game press R</p>
          
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
   
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

right click on the webpage and click on inspect source then navigate to your page.
maybe start with just getting a image on a canvas on your webpage first then add a shape or somthing. you likely have many errors from copy pasting like this and it will be easier to debug if you add features in smaller increments. this way you will know what action you took broke it.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. It is an instruction on how to debug. This should be a comment, but not an answer.

Comment: they asked, "What can I try next?" i answered "right click on the webpage and click on inspect source" as well as some troubbleshooting methoods they could try, these are things they "can try next" no?  just tring to help a clearly new person out  @Rabbid76 https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757 you are making meta comments

Comment: Nevertheless, this is not an answer to the question and does not solve the problem.